# Select query by filtering multiple rows

Tags: oracle

I have a table like this:

```
col | status
----+-------
1   |  0
1   |  1
2   |  1
2   |  2
3   |  1
3   |  0
```

I want to select only the row with having max status value. But also want to ignore if there is any 0 in status. So expected rows would be as follows (I am ignoring 1 and 3 for having status = 0).

```
col | status
----+-------
2   |  2
```

I only can pick the rows based on max(). But when I add another clause to filter the zero, it doesn't work.

```
SELECT col, max(status)
  FROM my_table
 WHERE
    (select count(*) 
    from my_table t1
    where t1.col = col
    and status = 0) = 0 
 GROUP BY col;
```

Any guide will do for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT col, MAX(STATUS)
FROM tab
GROUP BY col
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

**[DBFiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f2b476c01046d253cacbd383a2852ae7)**

---

If your minimal value for `STATUS` is `0` then you could use:

```
SELECT col, MAX(STATUS)
FROM tab
GROUP BY col
HAVING MIN(STATUS) > 0;
```

Comment: huh, you must be kidding!!! Thanks. Will accept as answer once I am allowed to accept.

Comment: Wouldn't HAVING MIN(status) > 0 have been more self explanatory?

Comment: @CaiusJard Yes, I thought about it as well  but I don't have info about different status values (like -1,-2). `SUM()` is quite general and safer in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a novice at SQL, but I'm sure rank() will serve the purpose.

```
select tabl.col, tabl.status from
(select col, status, rank over(status desc) as rnk
from tab where status = 0) tabl
where tabl.rnk = 1
and rownum = 1;
```

Comment: i understand where you're going with this but it's unlikely to be what the OP wants for a few reasons; it makes no attempt to exclude items that have a status of 0 in any row, and it might also return more than one row for an item if the status is highest twice with equal value

Comment: @CaiusJard,
Updated my query. Hope this addresses your comments :)